# How to embed link tag in textview using RSS in a Android

Tags: android, rss, textview

I had made a basic rss reader that reads the feed and display it in listview, then i further tried to improve it by adding tabs and writing a custom adapter,now the next step i want to achieve is to provide the basic capability that whenever a headline (displayed through a textview) is clicked/touched the link associated with it (link has been extracted throught he rss/xml) is launched in the browser. Now, i know that launching the link into browser is an easy one step affair using URI, whats causing trouble is how do i keep the link with the textview it is associated with?

I have implemented the onclicklistener all i need to figure out is how can the retrieval of relevant link can be achieved so that i can make a URI out of it and launch it in the browser.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a wrapper object with the title and the url. then fill the list view with those objects, and get the url to fire the browser activity.

Something like:

```
class RssObect {
    string title;
    string url;

    //contructors

    //getters and setters
}
```

Then on the adapter set the list something like `List<RssObect> list = getRssFeed(...)`.... 
Then on item click listener just use the current item selected `(list.get(selected).getUrl());`

Comment: Oh yes i already have done sth similar to serve a different cause, let me try if it works.Thanks :)